# pandas DataFrame has only one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have problem listing DataFrame rows. The below function returns only one row (if indented returns first row, if not indented returns the last one). Does anyone knows where's the problem?

```
def ols_regression(formula, framedict):
    for yp in framedict.keys():
        ols_model = ols(formula, framedict[str(yp)]).fit()
        year = int(yp[:-5])    
        params = ols_model.params

        d = (dict(yp = yp, year = year, formula=formula, R_squared=ols_model.rsquared,
            intercept = params.values[0], DP1 = params.values[1], I = params.values[2], P = params.values[3],  
            p_intercept = ols_model.pvalues[0], p_DP1 = ols_model.pvalues[1], p_I = ols_model.pvalues[2], 
            p_P = ols_model.pvalues[3]))

    return pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem with appending the dictionary to array.

```
def ols_regression(formula, framedict):

    arr = []

    for yp in framedict.keys():
        ols_model = ols(formula, framedict[str(yp)]).fit()
        year = int(yp[:-5])    
        params = ols_model.params

        arr.append(dict(yp = yp, year = year, formula=formula, R_squared=int(ols_model.rsquared),
            intercept = params.values[0], DP1 = params.values[1], I = params.values[2], P = params.values[3],  
            p_intercept = ols_model.pvalues[0], p_DP1 = ols_model.pvalues[1], p_I = ols_model.pvalues[2], 
            p_P = ols_model.pvalues[3]))

    return pd.DataFrame(arr)
```